# Thread.sleep While a GIF is Playing

Tags: java, multithreading, paint

I'm trying to make a game, and there is a credits button. When you click the credits button, a gif appears and rolls downwards like the credits at the end of a movie. The GIF lasts for 10.25 seconds. I'm trying to draw something when the GIF ends, but the only way to detect that is by doing Thread.sleep(10250); and then drawing it. However, the Thread.sleep is pausing the gif, then resuming it after 10 seconds.
Here is the relevant code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(onFrontPage == true){
            g2.drawImage(frontpage, 0, 0, this);
        }
        if(credits == true){
            g2.drawImage(creditsgif, 0, 0, this);
        }
        if(aftercredits == true){
            g2.drawImage(creditsimg, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }



    // Checks credits button
    if(e.getX() > 549 && e.getY() > 458 && e.getX() < 749 && e.getY() < 534){
        credits = true;
        onFrontPage = false;
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        credits = false;
        aftercredits = true;
        repaint();

    }
```

I'm trying to draw the image "creditsimg" after the gif is finished, but the Thread sleep is pausing the gif at the beginning for 10 seconds and then starting the gif. How can I make the Thread.sleep work in the background so it doesn't interfere with the gif?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(credits == true){
  Thread th=new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      g2.drawImage(creditsgif, 0, 0, null);
    }
  };
  th.start();
}
```

you may have to make some variables final or pass them in the constructor of the thread.

Comment: Can't use the "this" keyword for the ImageObserver, what do I use in place of it? In tutorials I've watched it was always "this" and they never explained what the ImageObserver is so...